# sqlite database in persian language

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, arabic, farsi

I tried to create a sqlite database from a csv file. I did it as it is said in this page : [using your own sqlite db in android](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) and this : [import csv to sqlite](http://www.haakseth.com/?p=85)

but the problem is when the table contains data in farsi/arabic language. sqlite shows that character as "_".
what should I do?

PS. I want to use this DB in an android project.

edit:
I import csv to sqlite using this code:

```
CREATE TABLE "android_metadata"("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US');
CREATE TABLE "addresses"(_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
nametext, meaning text);
.separator ","
.import test.csv mydb
```

Comment: How do you import the CSV to the database?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev , u'v just added the code

Comment: @shohreh : How can I sort a field based on the Persian word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sqlite supports UTF-8, UTF-16 and this is quite enough to store arabic or persian.

Most probably you get "_" because the import tool expects different charset than the charset of your original file.

Answer (score 1):

Persian/Farsi is not supported in Android up to version 4.0, but there are some things that might help you listed [here](http://www.pedramhayati.com/2011/05/15/persianfarsi-language-for-android/).

I also came across [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205509/persian-numbers-in-sql-server-2005) about Persian numbers in SQL, though I'm not sure that will help at all.

I found a similar question to yours: [C# - Does Sqlite database support persian/arabic encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021059/does-sqlite-database-support-persian-arabic-encoding)
and this seems to give an unfortunately negative answer:

> In short: No.
>
> SQLite support only a very, very limited number of encodings: UTF-8 and UTF-16 (multiple varieties).
>
> Fortunately, UTF-8 is perfectly suitable for expressing Arabic or Persian, or any other language (including Klingon, should the fancy grab you).
>
> It is posible, of course, that some other part of your toolchain is bungling the encoding, check the documentation for the C#.net SQLite wrapper, and your Forms code.

Comment: there is no problem with android. the problem is when i convert csv to sqlite .db file. after importing the csv file, persian characters change to "_"

Comment: Right, but according to the quote I listed above, from the third link, Sqlite doesn't support persion/arabic encoding, so you may need to do some parsing/conversion on the CSV file to change the persion/arabic characters to something that SQLite can handle.