# persian/arabic search in sqlite android gives bad result

Tags: android, sqlite, arabic, persian, select-query

i have a problem with sqlite database. it seems to not support full persian/arabic characters. when i search some fields based on persian chars, most of the times Sqlite can't recognize those chars.

i insert data into database by copy them from HTML file. so when i type string and search, no result show. but if i copy string and search, it works.

The string from the HTML file is:

> "احكام خمس"

The typed string is:

> "احکام خمس"

Comment: SQLite doesn't know about languages; it simply compares Unicode characters. Show examples of the strings that you think should match.

Comment: i tried select some field in sqlite browser and eclipse.
and for some words i get no result.
this is my query in SQLite Browser :
select part from table where season = 'خمس';
it seems to sqlite not recognize 'خمس'.
but when i search طهارت it gives good result.
i do the same thing in eclipse and get same results.

Comment: And what is the string in the table that you think should match?

Comment: the string is 'خمس' and i search for it. when i copy 'خمس' from table cell it works, but when i type it, no result return.

Comment: The string in your comment is identical with that in the question. Did you copy it from the table cell when writing the comment?

Comment: no i type it. try 'احکام خمس' and see it works or not !!!

Comment: it seems SQLite has problem with space in persian/arabic query !!! in addition it has problem with ی . i replaced ی and ي and it worked. but i don't know how to fix space.

Comment: What space? There is no space in your query `...where season = 'خمس'`. Please edit the question to show both the string in the table and the string you want to match it with.

Comment: Please show the actual strings!

Comment: the HTML one is "احكام خمس"
and typed one "احکام خمس"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These strings are different.

The HTML string begins with the characters U+0627, U+062D, and U+0643 (Alef, Hah, and Kaf).

The third character of the typed string is not U+0643 but U+06A9 (Keheh).

Comment: oh its so bad!!! i have both typed and copied data in my database, and i don't know how to fix it. when i type, SQLite can't show copied data, and if i copy it can't show typed data !!!

Comment: ok, i find a solution. in SQLite browser i should to replace for all column arabic chars with persian chars to get good result when i type.
update table set column = replace(column, "ي", "ی");
update table set column = replace(column, "ك", "ک");

Answer (score 5):

Sqlite is very simple supported persian/arabic.
read this link. [sqlite database in persian language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862930/sqlite-database-in-persian-language)

Comment: as i said i searched too much, but i can't solve my problem. in comment above you can see my full problem.

Comment: @hojjatreyhane Sqlite support is UTF-16. I don't know very well UTF-16, but UTF-16 will support Persian and Arabic. Try to it.

Comment: @Amadas Actually, SQLite uses UTF-8 by default (but this does not matter because the Android libraries automatically convert from/to the encoding used for Java strings).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select part from table where season = N'خمس';
```

If that not help, try using operators `like` and `%`.

I'm already using `SQLite` for more than 2 years in Persian supported projects in production environments and has no problem at all.

**Udate:**

I'm using `SQLite` via `NHibernate`. So myself never generate or write a query. To be honest never noticed how `NHibernate` send queries to `SQLite`.

Comment: in sqlite browser when i put N before string it crashes. i used like, but the result was similar. maybe in eclipse it will work!!!