# How to fetch result from sql Lite DB against arabic text?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

i am facing problems while reading data from SQl Lite Database against arabic data that i have stored. Arabic text is saved correctly in my Db. I am using following code.

```
if(language == "arabic"){
    //alert(value);
    db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql('SELECT *  FROM BRANDOFFERS WHERE brandId IN (SELECT id FROM BRANDS WHERE nameArabic="'+value+'") ', [], fillDiscountType, errorCB);}, errorCB);
}else{
    db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql('SELECT *  FROM BRANDOFFERS WHERE brandId IN (SELECT id FROM BRANDS WHERE name="'+value+'") ', [], fillDiscountType, errorCB);}, errorCB);
```

In case of arabic it not fetching any result but against english i am getting correct results. Moreover, I tried to display the arabic text from sqllite DB, it is showing right. But, i don't why it can't able to search with the arabic text.In

Comment: are u testing in android ?

Comment: can u test this : http://blog.gabemastey.com/post/42979676803/arabic-fonts-on-ios-android-webkit-for-phonegap-app

Comment: yes am doing it in android

Comment: Could this possibly be something similar to [persian/arabic search in sqlite android gives bad result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295771/persian-arabic-search-in-sqlite-android-gives-bad-result)? Are you sure that both strings are using the same Unicode characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured it out. I used the following piece of code

```
var getServerAtabicText = brands[i].nameArabic;  //Arabic text
var decodedArabicText = $('<div/>').html(getServerAtabicText).text();
```

before saving arabic text into SQL lite DB. Then i simply run the same code:

```
if(language == "arabic"){
//alert(value);
db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql('SELECT *  FROM BRANDOFFERS WHERE brandId IN (SELECT id FROM BRANDS WHERE nameArabic="'+value+'") ', [], fillDiscountType, errorCB);}, errorCB);
}else{
db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql('SELECT *  FROM BRANDOFFERS WHERE brandId IN (SELECT id FROM BRANDS WHERE name="'+value+'") ', [], fillDiscountType, errorCB);}, errorCB);
```

for query my data and it works (: