# How to isert into Urdu into SQLITE database

Tags: c#, database

How to insert Urdu or multi-languages in SQLite database using c# through the Unicode UTF encoding but the resulted as  (????????????) how to read exact data from SQLite database. I search a lot on internet but could not find a solution. Please help me to solve this problem.
I have already tried by the connection string but it don't work
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Please could you give details about the schema of the database, how you're obtaining the text to start with, how you're inserting it into the database, and how you're then reading it? Any of these could cause a problem.

Comment: do you have NVARCHAR datatype ?

Comment: @Abdul Rehman This may give you some insight. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862930/sqlite-database-in-persian-language